# I had inserted a jQuery tab in my site. It was working fine till sometime ago. Suddenly it stopped working. Can someone figure out the problem?

Tags: jquery, drupal-6, jquery-ui-tabs

I had inserted two jQuery tabs on my site. One div container had the id - tabs and another had the id tabs-for-views.

Both of them were working fine till sometime ago, until i made some changes. I don't remember what the exact changes were..

Right now, the first tab uses the jQuery UI theme I am using. As in, I can see the tab navigation and content panels - but on clicking the tabs nothing happens. But the second (tabs-for-views) is not even converted to proper tabs format.

I am using the Drupal CMS for this site.

the tabs can be found on this page:
http://betterclassofleaders.co.cc/whackk/

this is the jquery ui css file i am using: (insert first link)sites/default/themes/whack_custom/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css

Comment: I don't know whats wrong, just trying to provide more information to your question... 
Error: c.Event is not a function
Source file: http://betterclassofleaders.co.cc/whackk/sites/default/themes/whack_custom/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js
Line: 9

Comment: @Delan : sorry i dont' understand what you are trying to say.

@BrunoLM : ya, saw that error in firebug. dont have a clue what it means. it's in the jquery ui script file

Comment: HTML is sent as text/html, then parsed as HTML. XHTML is sent as application/xhtml+xml and parsed using an XML parser. You are sending XHTML as text/html, which is wrong. It causes many problems and shouldn't be done (except for Internet Explorer).

Comment: Did you happen to modify the file? strangely the version inside the js file says its version 1.7.3 and your filename same its 1.7.2!

Comment: @Delan: I see. So, I should just remove the doctype or set it it to html 4.0, right?

Comment: @Abdel: I downloaded a new version of jquery ui (1.7.3), but all my pages have the file name set to 1.7.2. I couldn't bother changing the path in other file so i just changed the file names for the UI js and css files. I am lazy like that :P

Comment: No. Don't ever remove the Doctype. Either use HTML (sent as text/html) or XHTML (sent as application/xhtml+xml). Here, read this post I wrote a while ago, it'll clear everything up: http://azabani.com/7

Comment: @Delan : corrected the doctype part. I dont think that was the problem.. Thanks anyways.

Comment: You don't remember what exact changes you did? I gather you're not using source control, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI 1.7.2 requires jQuery 1.3.2. You're using jQuery 1.2.6 on your Drupal website.

You can either update the jQuery by using the [jQuery Update module 6.x-2.0](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) or downgrade your jQuery UI to 1.6. :)

Also, just about your upgrade from 1.7.2 to 1.7.3. The update is just for compatibility fixes for jQuery 1.4, so it's unnecessary for you to do the upgrade since you're not using jQuery 1.4.

Comment: as a matter of fact I am using the jquery update module (version: 6.x-2.x - as seen on the module list page). So i doubt thats causing the problem.

Comment: Nope. Running $.fn.jquery on Firebug, I can see you're using 1.2.6. Also, looking at [this file](http://betterclassofleaders.co.cc/whackk/misc/jquery.js).

Comment: hmm. I see your point. But I do have the jQuery update module enabled. Doesn't it automatically replace the jquery.js file in the misc folder with 1.3.2?

Comment: the upgrade to 1.7.3 was not a conscious decision. I just decided to grab a new jui file because of my problem. it turned out to .3 instead of .2

Comment: If the module is enabled, you should see that it includes the file from `/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery.min.js` instead of `/misc/jquery.js`. I think you might have a module conflict of some sort. Try disabling and re-enabling the module?

Comment: tried the re-enabling path. at least three times. won't work. and it's still using the original jquery.
will it cause any problems if i just repalce /misc/jquery.js with the file in jquery update's replace folder?

Comment: yes. thats it. i replaced /misc/jquery.js with jquery.min.js (1.3.2) and renamed it to jquery.js. 
Problem solved!

Comment: Haha, that's rather hacky. There might be problems with that. Maybe you should check the issue queue for the jquery_update module? Just in case you run into problems. I couldn't find anything though.

Comment: Ya, i thought so too. Earlier I was reluctant to go that way. But then, I decided, what the heck, let's try. Anyways, I copied the other files in the replace folder too. So i suppose there shouldn't be any problems. Cos that's what it basically does anyways. Or atleast should.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: apparently, the main problem was being caused by the lightbox2 module.